# GWT home page to login page to actual app example redirecting issue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, authentication

I am truly struggling with this - i have checked all of the other Stack overflow pages and while this may seem like a duplicate question there are NO other answers I can find anywhere besides potentially using multiple modules (even though this does not seem correct)

All i want to do is have a set of static pages making up a website for my main page, the Login page (i plan to use RequestFactory to pull back the user permissions to display stuff for the app from here - somebody suggested in another post such as this to do it from a "Non-GWT" page - that doesn't sound correct to me), and then when the user logs in successfully he gets directed to the actual app with certain things being displayed based on his current permissions.

Now, i have implemented little test projects with multiple JSPs to do redirects using Window.Location.replace("...") but then I have no idea how to actually populate that particular page with what I want to be replaced.

From just 1 GWT app is it possible to have a full web page in static HTML files (or even JSPs i don't care), a Login Page, and the actual App.

And if this is so, How do you do this?

I use RootLayoutPanel.get() to load up my main App - how does it know which RootLayoutPanel to actually use - i've spent hours fighting with this and a lot of the tutorials / answers to the questions don't provide much depth as to how to actually go about implementing anything.  There is obviously something i'm just missing

I want to do something exactly like the example in the showcase: https://www.blueworkslive.com/#!gettingStarted:overview

If you use chrome and check the tags every single page on there says GWT 2.4, so it's definitely not like one answer i came across saying "don't use GWT for the login".  This seems like it should be something simple that I just... am not finding or honestly am not getting from any of the examples.

This is close to the last step of my project and any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

---

I'm using Apache Shiro with GAE, Objectify for a database and RequestFactory - there is only one main html page and the app is simply calling getRootLayoutPanel to load the app.  not sure if any of that is useful.

implementing the page isn't the issue it's just the redirecting

Answer (score 1):

To login on GAE, via Google account or federated login, you need to redirect your user to login page. Since you run GWT, which usually only has one page, you have two choices:

1. Do the normal redirect to login page - in this case browser will go to login page and you will loose GWT app state. After login, you can be redirected back to GWT app. As said - GWT app state will be lost. This is the simple way.
2. Open the login page in child window or iframe. Set destination URL to a page that closes the window (actually it must install a javascript parent hook, that destination page calls). When login is done, destination page calls JS hook, which notifies parent page thet login procedure is over, closes the child window/iframe and continues. This is more complex, some login pages do not like iframes (in case of OpenID login), but it retains your GWT app state.

To answer your question:

Yes it's possible to have multiple pages in a GWT project (GWT pages/modules and static files). Of course, as you navigate from page to page, you will loose app state. GWT module is only "active" as long as page is loaded in browser.

Comment: going off of option 1 - does this sound in any way correct (this is what i'm implementing right now - just started working on it).  at login, use a request factory to validate an empty user - the failure will redirect to the main jsp - the main jsp will have a link to the login jsp - the login jsp will have an HttpServlet to use the request factory to do a login - if the login succeeds from the servlet it will redirect to the main app - is this at all logical or am i way off - i'm just wondering before i go about doing all this?  Thank you

Comment: You dont need your own login page. Login link on main page should take you to Google login page. Google login url is generated by 'UserService.createLoginUrl'.

Comment: i saw you could do this in the MobileWebAppExample that comes with GWT - but here's the only problem.. the app i'm working on needs to accept any users regardless of gmail accounts - if i do the UserService.createLoginUrl won't this only let people sign in with their google accounts? ... also i think i might have been doing something stupid - i think i can do all the jsp stuff internally to GWT ... i'm working on it right now